Mapping Keycloak Group and Role
I'm using Keycloak 18.0
I've created several groups and subgroups and assigned some roles depending on the subgroup like

/proj1/admin - ADMIN_ROLE
/proj2/editor - EDITOR_ROLE

etc.

Inner roles:

I also created a user and joined to

/proj1/editor
/proj1/reader
/projectttt/editor

subgroups
Finally, I've created a new Group Membership mapper in profile Client Scope so that groups are included in a JWT token:

In the resulting decoded JWT token in a payload I receive the following:
{
  "exp": 1731958821,
  "iat": 1731940821,
  "jti": "57c7823a-1473-4f04-91ee-8d1d8dcd619e",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/local",
  "aud": "lair",
  "sub": "3a877b31-bea8-48ce-8ffd-41901739383b",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "test",
  "session_state": "ad47895c-9ee3-4dac-a979-ad6ffb0a52a5",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "http://localhost:8080"
  ],
  "scope": "profile spa_scope email",
  "sid": "ad47895c-9ee3-4dac-a979-ad6ffb0a52a5",
  "email_verified": true,
  "roles": [
    "offline_access",
    "uma_authorization",
    "READER_ROLE",
    "default-roles-local",
    "EDITOR_ROLE"
  ],
  "name": "qwewqe sadsad",
  "groups": [
    "/proj1/editor",
    "/projectttt/editor",
    "/proj1/reader"
  ],
  "preferred_username": "test",
  "given_name": "qwewqe",
  "family_name": "sadsad"
}

However, as you can notice, I can't differ one EDITOR_ROLE from another one. They are just saved in a JWT token as a set of values under roles
Is it possible to associate group and its corresponding role to separate one subgroup role from another one like:
{
pseudo
...
"groups": {
    "/proj1/editor": "EDITOR_ROLE",
    "/projectttt/editor": "EDITOR_ROLE",
    "/proj1/reader": "READER_ROLE"
  }
...
}

Would be thankful for any assistance!

Any reason why you cannot update to use the latest Keycloak?

@Lukman This is related to infrastucture restrictions. Nevertheless, I would appreciate any advice despite Keycloak version
